# Don't break page for new chapter unless chapter heading won't fully fit on current page

Tags: page-breaking, memoir, chapters

I am using the `memoir` class.

I'm trying to ensure that new chapters happen on the same page as the last one, except in cases where parts of the chapter heading would have been split across two pages.

This is what I've tried:

```
\renewcommand{\clearforchapter}{}
```

Which gives me this:

[image: good]

But also this:

[image: bad]

Is there a simple solution so that the new chapter starts on a new page except in the case where part of it would be split across two pages, in which case there is a page break?

NOTE: here is my custom chapter heading code, although it **might not be relevant at all and is not part of my question** but is included for the sake of completeness:

```
\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}
  \mbox{}\\\mbox{}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\itshape\large}
\settoheight{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont 1}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering \chapnumfont Chapter \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 0.5\onelineskip}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering \vphantom{\chapnumfont 1}\afterchapternum}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Large}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering \chaptitlefont #1
    \\\mbox{}\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1\onelineskip}
```

Comment: There is a way to do this, but not easy, but in my point of view, this is ugly: `Chapter` comes from `capitulum`, meaning (small) head --> a chapter should start on the head of a page, not somewhere in between

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In general I agree, but this an unconventional book, it's actually a very long and rambling dialogue, where the chapters are only there for convenience so the reader can easily find a part of the discussion by topic.

Comment: I see. Well, I imagine, that one way is to put the chapter title into an unbreakable box. It must appear on the page if there is enough space or it will be placed on the next page.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sounds like a good idea. I will research how to do this (I'm a LaTeX newbie) but in the meantime I hope someone posts this as a full solution with sample code, because it sounds reasonable.

Comment: I would say, a `\parbox` must be sufficient already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\needspace` macro (directly available in `memoir`, for other classes there's the `needspace` package).

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\clearforchapter}{}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{%
  \par
  \needspace{10\onelineskip}
  \vspace{\beforechapskip}
  \mbox{}\\\mbox{}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\itshape\large}
\settoheight{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont 1}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering \chapnumfont Chapter \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 0.5\onelineskip}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering \vphantom{\chapnumfont 1}\afterchapternum}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Large}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering \chaptitlefont #1
    \\\mbox{}\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1\onelineskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Justin narrates the manner of his conversion}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Justin describes his studies in philosophy}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Justin does some other things}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works amazingly!

Comment: Wish I could upvote a second time for chapter 3's title.